# Strange characters before line printing

Tags: python, character

When I try to print random lines from a txt file (UTF-8 encoded on Notepad) I get some weird characters before each text.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
OPENVERB1 = open('verb1.txt').read().splitlines()
VERB1 = random.choice(OPENVERB1)
print VERB1
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the text within verb1.txt that you are trying to print?

Comment: Sounds like your file has a bunch of extra weird invisible characters in it, and your terminal isn't interpreting the bytes as UTF-8, so the bytes are getting interpreted as visible characters.

Comment: of course!
The txt file has a space before each line. Now I wonder it may be the case:
 to be
 to have
 to do
 to say
 to go
 to get
 to make
 to know
etc

Comment: You really should open UTF-8 files in binary mode. And seriously consider switching to Python 3. It's so easy to make a mess of Unicode in Python 2. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The problem is each line in my txt file starts with a space. I just removed them all and add the space in my print command.

Comment: Those probably weren't actually spaces.